# How to filtering multiple columns in SPGridView

Tags: 2010, web-part, spgridview

I have a webpart with SpGridView. I bind it with ObjectDataSource.

I want filtering multiple columns.

I set AllowFiltering for spgrid:

```
  grid.AllowFiltering = true;
  grid.FilterDataFields = ",Name,Region,Total Sales";
  grid.FilteredDataSourcePropertyName = "FilterExpression";
  grid.FilteredDataSourcePropertyFormat = "{1} = '{0}'";
```

and set ObjectDataSource

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="ds"  SelectMethod="GetTable"  ></asp:ObjectDataSource>

   ds.ObjectCreating += new ObjectDataSourceObjectEventHandler(ds_ObjectCreating);
  void ds_ObjectCreating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        myDataTable = new DataTableWrapper(sourceDataTable);

        e.ObjectInstance = myDataTable;
    }

     sourceDataTable = list.GetItems(quary).GetDataTable();
        myDataTable = new DataTableWrapper(sourceDataTable);
        Type t = myDataTable.GetType();
        ds.TypeName = t.AssemblyQualifiedName;

        grid.DataSourceID = "ds";
        grid.DataBind();
```

But when i click filter i get error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ObjectDatasource takes the TypeName of your data source, not the Qualified name.
You need to modify this

```
Type t = myDataTable.GetType();
    ds.TypeName = t.AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

so you set the TypeName property to the type name for example "My.ObjectDataSource.NorthwindData" instead of "My.ObjectDataSource.NorthwindData, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e08"

Comment: I don't underestand. :(

Comment: Reading you error message again, I think i understand that it works the first time, but as soon as you click on filter it throws an error. You error message says that you have not set the TypeName property when you click. So i believe that your problem is that when you do postbacks for your grid your not handling the setting of the TypeName again.

Comment: in load i set setting of the TypeName but don't word and get error.

Comment: I don't understand the last part of your message "but don't word and get error"?

Comment: Sorry, I have the wrong type."don't work and get error"

Comment: Ah, i understand. It is because your using the AssemblyQualifiedName attribute of the variable t. using this will return a string that looks like this "My.ObjectDataSource.NorthwindData, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e08". However you need a string that looks like this "My.ObjectDataSource.NorthwindData" when setting the TypeName property on the ObjectDataSource. Of course replacing it with your own namespace and class name.

Comment: When i use (t.AssemblyQualifiedName), it is set AssemblyQualifiedName looks like value as you said.

Comment: If you get the short string from AssemblyQualifiedName. Then you have a postback issue and the TypeName is not set on the postbacks. i think you should just try setting you type staticly like this <asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="ds"  SelectMethod="GetTable" TypeName="Your.Custom.Type" ></asp:ObjectDataSource> and when you know that works with your filtering, you can try doing it dynamically.

Comment: I set this setting in PageLoad.

Comment: Show me the code.

Comment: I defined the ObjectDataSource in webpart class and my problem was solved :) .. Thanks a lot.